# MATLAB: Separate a table according to the separation of the rows in a string

Tags: string, matlab, datatable

I would like to separate a table's coulombs to correspond with the number and data of the string I would like to load into the table. Otherwise said, if I have a 2x1 string, I would like to have a table in which the information from the two different rows remain separate (**But for a nx1 string**).

Here is my example and attempt of doing it:

```
String = ["Random info in middle one, "+ ...
        "Random info still continues. ",
        "Random info in middle two. "+ ...
        "Random info still continues. "];

    documents_Middle = tokenizedDocument(String);
    tdetails = tokenDetails(documents_Middle);
    
    for y=1:height(tdetails)
    Table_RandomInfoMiddle(y,:) = tdetails(y,{'Token','Type'});
    end
```

Notice the 2x1 string, thus each row has its own unique information.
Right now all the information of my 2x1 string is just thrown into one single table like this:

[image]

The result I'm hoping for would look something like this(image cut to fit idea of answer):

[image]

The main idea is to get this information separate.

All help is appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You won't be able to have different columns with the same name.
I suggest you do something like the following. Construct two variables, `variableNames` and `variables`, which contain the tokens and the types. Then use those to create the table:

```
s = ["Random info in middle one, "+ ...
            "Random info still continues. ",
            "Random info in middle two. "+ ...
            "Random info still continues. "];
t = table();
d = tokenizedDocument(s);

variableNames = [];
variables = [];

for n=1:length(d)
 variableNames = [variableNames {sprintf('Tokens for sentence %d',n)} {sprintf('Type for sentence %d',n)}];
 variables = [variables {d(n).tokenDetails.Token} {d(n).tokenDetails.Type}];
end

table(variables{:},'VariableNames',variableNames)

ans =

  11×4 table

    Tokens for sentence 1    Type for sentence 1    Tokens for sentence 2    Type for sentence 2
    _____________________    ___________________    _____________________    ___________________

         "Random"                letters                 "Random"                letters        
         "info"                  letters                 "info"                  letters        
         "in"                    letters                 "in"                    letters        
         "middle"                letters                 "middle"                letters        
         "one"                   letters                 "two"                   letters        
         ","                     punctuation             "."                     punctuation    
         "Random"                letters                 "Random"                letters        
         "info"                  letters                 "info"                  letters        
         "still"                 letters                 "still"                 letters        
         "continues"             letters                 "continues"             letters        
         "."                     punctuation             "."                     punctuation
```

Comment: Thanks! Just one more question. The example above just happened to have the same amount of rows. If one of the sentences in the above string hast just one word more, I get the error: "All table variables must have the same number of rows.". Is there a workaround to this problem (without contaminating the data with other characters or spaces)?

Comment: You'll need to populate smaller entries so that you have the same number of rows

Comment: Thanks that makes sense yes. The thing is the information needs to remain untouched. My idea is to use the NaNs in order to equal the amount of rows. The tricky part is to make it work for any amount of strings, with all the other strings needing to fill up to match the longest string. I'm yet without success, would you be so kind to help again? Thank you.

Comment: @Div Open a new question

Comment: Thanks. Done, with my attempt included. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64643868/matlab-equal-the-rows-of-a-table