# MATLAB: Count punctuation marks in table columns

Tags: matlab, for-loop, datatable, count

I'm trying to find the amount of sentences in this table:

[image]

Download Table here: http://www.mediafire.com/file/m81vtdo6bdd7bw8/Table_RandomInfoMiddle.mat/file

As you can see by the full-stops, there is one sentence in column one, and 2 sentences in column 3.
At the end of the day I desire to have a table with nothing but punctuation marks(with the exception of place holders like "", to keep the table rows the same length) that indicate the end of a sentence(Like "." or "?" or "!"), in order to calculate the total number of punctuation marks of each column.
This is my code(Yet unsuccessful):

```
EqualCoumns = [2:2:max(width(Table_RandomInfoMiddle))];
for t=EqualCoumns
MiddleOnlySentenceIndicators = Table_RandomInfoMiddle((Table_RandomInfoMiddle{:, t}=='punctuation'),:);
%Reomve all but "!.?" = Which is the only sentence enders
    MiddleOnlySentenceIndicators(MiddleOnlySentenceIndicators{:, t} == ',', :) = [];
    MiddleOnlySentenceIndicators(MiddleOnlySentenceIndicators{:, t} == ';', :) = [];
    MiddleOnlySentenceIndicators(MiddleOnlySentenceIndicators{:, t} == ':', :) = [];
    MiddleOnlySentenceIndicators(MiddleOnlySentenceIndicators{:, t} == '-', :) = [];
MiddleSentence_Nr(t) =  height(MiddleOnlySentenceIndicators);
end
```

Right now this is almost giving good results, there is a little mistake somewhere.
(In the answer I would like to request only one thing, that I might have access to the results in the same table like form, it should look something like this(edited):

[image]

Any help will be appreciated.
Thank you!

Comment: *At the end of the day I desire to have a table with nothing but punctuation marks that indicate the end of a sentence, and then have the total number of punctuation marks of each column.* That's not what the final screenshot shows. Could you clarify?

Comment: @Paolo You are right. I have edited the phrasing to be more specific. The <missing> is just there to have the table in tack in that each column needs the same amount of rows. By having such a final table, I would like to count the amount of punctuation marks of each column.

Comment: Could you update the the screenshot to show the desired output? It should include a count right? I don't see that in the screenshot

Comment: @Paolo Thanks. The output table is correct. I would like to calculate the amount of punctuation marks from this table.

Answer (score 0):

If we use the table from my [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64696720/3390419), `t`, we can use the following solution:

```
punctuation_table = table();
for col=1:size(t,2)
    column_name = sprintf('Punctuation count for column %d',col);
    punctuation_table.(column_name) = nnz(ismember(t(:,col).Variables,{'?',',','.','!'}));
end
```

which will create a table like this:

```
punctuation_table =

1×4 table

Punctuation count for column 1    Punctuation count for column 2    Punctuation count for column 3    Punctuation count for column 4
______________________________    ______________________________    ______________________________    ______________________________

              2                                 0                                 2                                 0
```

Comment: @ Paolo. Thanks again. How would you go about doing the opposite, that is to determine the amount of words? See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64796385/matlab-count-the-occurrences-of-a-specific-string-in-table-columns