# MATLAB: Count string occurrences in table columns

Tags: string, matlab, datatable, count

I'm trying to find the amount of words in this table:
[image]

Download Table here: http://www.mediafire.com/file/m81vtdo6bdd7bw8/Table_RandomInfoMiddle.mat/file

Words are indicated by the "Type" criteria, being "letters". The key thing to notice is that not everything in the table is a word, and that the entry "" registers as a word. In other words I need to determine the amount of words, by only counting "letters", except if it is a "missing".

Here is my attempt (Yet unsuccessful - Notice the two mentions of "Problem area"):

```
for col=1:size(Table_RandomInfoMiddle,2)
    column_name = sprintf('Words count for column %d',col);
    MiddleWordsType_table.(column_name) = nnz(ismember(Table_RandomInfoMiddle(:,col).Variables,{'letters'}));
    MiddleWordsExclusionType_table.(column_name) = nnz(ismember(Table_RandomInfoMiddle(:,col).Variables,{'<missing>'})); %Problem area
end
%Call data from table
    MiddleWordsType = table2array(MiddleWordsType_table);
    MiddleWordsExclusionType = table2array(MiddleWordsExclusionType_table); %Problem area
%Take out zeros where "Type" was
    MiddleWordsTotal_Nr = MiddleWordsType(MiddleWordsType~=0); 
    MiddleWordsExclusionTotal_Nr = MiddleWordsExclusionType(MiddleWordsExclusionType~=0);
%Final answer
    FinalMiddleWordsTotal_Nr = MiddleWordsTotal_Nr-MiddleWordsExclusionTotal_Nr;
```

Any help will be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Does something like `N = numel( unique( tbl{ ismember(tbl{:,2}, 'letters'), 1 ) );` get you close? With or without the `unique` as it's not clear whether that's a requirement... Please provide a [mcve] with a simple input (one we can use, not an image!) and the expected output

Comment: @Wolfie You got it! This is the solution to use: `MiddleWordsType = numel(unique(Table_RandomInfoMiddle{ismember(Table_RandomInfoMiddle{:,2}, 'letters'), 1}));` Just one question, what am I doing wrong in looking for "missing", this is what I tried: `MiddleWordsExclusionType = numel(unique(Table_RandomInfoMiddle{ismember(Table_RandomInfoMiddle{:,1}, '<missing>'), 1}));?`

Comment: `<missing>` is a keyword in a categorical array, not literally the string `"<missing>"`, although I don't know your datatypes, I assume that's the issue. That's why it appears blue and *italicised* in the workspace. If you want to check specifically for missing values, you can is `ismissing( Table_RandomInfoMiddle{:,1} )` instead of `ismember`.

Comment: Thanks! You have solved the problem. How can I mark your answer as the recognized answer? Just one more question, notice the "problem area", in line 4 and 8 of the code above, you have given the solution to line 8, but how would you give the answer to line 4? This is what I thought: `MiddleWordsExclusionType_table.(column_name) = nnz(ismissing(Table_RandomInfoMiddle(:,col)));` , but this is not working.

Comment: I've converted my comments into a proper answer so you can mark as accepted (and upvote if you wish). It's not clear to me what your expected output is for line 4 - what is it meant to show? You're trying to assign a single value (the number of rows which are missing) to the whole column - do you just want to get rid of `nnz` so this column is true/false for whether the data is missing?

Comment: @Wolfie You are right, your solution for line 8 is sufficient, but when I will use another table for examination, I would just like to verify the answer obtained in line 8, by looking at the table in line 4. Basically, I would like to get the solution for line 4 with the same logic as line3. The solution I tried for line 4 was `MiddleWordsExclusionType_table.(column_name) = nnz(ismissing(Table_RandomInfoMiddle(:,col)));`, but this is not working. Thanks!

Comment: What does "not working" mean? You have an error message or the wrong result? Is it just that you need to use braces not brackets? `nnz(ismissing(Table_RandomInfoMiddle{:,col}))`

Comment: Thanks I did try that but no success. Yes you are right, I'm getting an error. The error is "Invalid field name: 'Words count for column 1'.". This comes from the `(column_name)` part of `MiddleWordsExclusionType_table.(column_name)`. I suspect only a syntax error in the use of `(column_name)`? What do you think?

Comment: You need to make the column name have no spaces, do this manually or by wrapping in `matlab.lang.makeValidName( __ )`. Column names follow the same rules as variable names

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the unique values from column 1 when column 2 satisfies some condition using

```
MiddleWordsType = numel( unique( ...
   Table_RandomInfoMiddle{ismember(Table_RandomInfoMiddle{:,2}, 'letters'), 1} ) );
```

`<missing>` is a keyword in a categorical array, not literally the string `"<missing>"`. That's why it appears blue and italicised in the workspace. If you want to check specifically for missing values, you can use this instead of `ismember`:

```
ismissing( Table_RandomInfoMiddle{:,1} )
```